# SQL Using Multiple Agregate Functions At Once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with some aggregate functions. I need to get 3 values from the table below. The amount of incidents per city, the amount of incidents per state, and the total amount of incidents. I believe I need to receive them in a single SQL function call.

```
STATE     CITY           Incidents    Week
AL       Birmingham         5          1
AL       Montgomery         1          1
CA       Sacramento         6          1 
CA       San Francisco      7          1
CA       Los Angeles        9          1
AL       Birmingham         4          2
AL       Montgomery         2          2
CA       Sacramento         8          2 
CA       San Francisco      5          2
CA       Los Angeles        8          2
```

Comment: This feels like a homework question. Although you're welcome to ask about homework questions here, it's considered polite to mention it, as then contributors will guide you to an answer rather than simply giving you one.

Comment: Your question doesn't match your title. Can you be more clear on your structure? Is your sample all from one table or two? Are you looking to count / sum or are you looking to join or both?

Comment: I suspect `ROLLUP` might be your friend ...

Answer (score 2):

Use [`grouping sets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select state, city, sum(incidents)
from t
group by grouping sets ( (state), (state, city), () );
```

Note:  I assume you need `state` and `city` together for the `city` rows.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are better off doing this in multiple queries instead of a single query.

If you absolutely *must* do this in a single query, one method is to use `ROLLUP`; another method would be to `UNION` the results of multiple queries.

NOTE: You never mentioned your table name. The code below assumes it's `Table`

This is our basic query. Easy enough to build, so long as you understand `GROUP BY`.

```sql
SELECT State, City, SUM(Incidents)
FROM Table
GROUP BY City, State;
```

### Using Rollup

[Adding `ROLLUP` is simple](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2007/09/21/aggregation-with-rollup/):

```sql
SELECT State, City, SUM(Incidents)
FROM Table
GROUP BY City, State WITH ROLLUP;
```

### Using Union

If you need to combine queries with `UNION`, you might do it this way:

1. Build your queries.
2. Modify your queries to have the same number of columns in a similar order
3. Apply `UNION` (probably, `UNION ALL`)

```sql
-- Build the three queries
-- By City
SELECT State, City, SUM(Incidents)
FROM Table
GROUP BY City, State;

-- By State
SELECT State, SUM(Incidents)
FROM Table
GROUP BY State;

-- Overall
SELECT SUM(Incidents)
FROM Table
; -- No GROUP BY!
```

The same queries, modified to have the same number of columns, and joined with a `UNION`:

```sql
  SELECT State, City, SUM(Incidents)
  FROM Table
  GROUP BY City, State
UNION ALL
  SELECT State, 'ALL' AS City, SUM(Incidents)
  FROM Table
  GROUP BY State
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'All States' AS State, 'ALL' AS City, SUM(Incidents)
  FROM Table
;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select CITY, count(*)
from tbl
group by CITY
```